PySpark for big data analytics, Assertion Error: facing issues converting string features using hashing and one-hot encoding
I am new to big data analytics and working on machine learning tasks with big data, specifically credit card fraud detection, using PySpark. However, I've encountered a roadblock. In my dataset, I have two string features that I need to convert to numerical values before building a model. I've tried various approaches such as one-hot encoding and hashing, but I haven't been successful.
How to solve this issue? or is there a better way to approach it?
These are the features and I want to convert the string values into numerical,

!pip3 install pyspark

# Importing the 'drive' module from the 'google.colab' library to mount Google Drive
from google.colab import drive

# Mounting the Google Drive at the '/content/drive' directory
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Importing the SparkSession class from the pyspark.sql module
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Creating a SparkSession named 'spark' to interact with Spark
# The 'master' parameter is set to "local[*]", which means Spark will run in local mode using all available cores
# The 'appName' parameter is set to 'Fraud Detection' to give a name to the Spark application
# The 'getOrCreate()' method ensures that if an existing SparkSession is available, it will be reused; otherwise, a new one will be created


spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .appName('Fraud Detection') \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "8g") \
        .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "16g") \
        .getOrCreate()

# load spark_df using spark
spark_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/big_data/transactions_train.csv',inferSchema=True, header =True)

# available columns in this spark_df
spark_df.columns

from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col

# Check for missing values in each column
missing_counts = spark_df.select([count(when(col(c).isNull() | isnan(col(c)), c)).alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns])
missing_counts.show()

# Check for missing values in any row
total_missing_count = spark_df.rdd.map(lambda row: sum([1 for x in row if x == None])).sum()
print("Total missing values in DataFrame: {}".format(total_missing_count))

from pyspark.sql.functions import when
# convert column type into numerical value
"""
  CASH-IN : 0,
  CASH-OUT : 1,
  DEBIT: 2,
  PAYMENT : 3,
  TRANSFER: 4,

"""
spark_df=spark_df.withColumn("type",
                             when(spark_df.type=="CASH_IN", 0)
                            .when(spark_df.type=="CASH_OUT", 1)
                            .when(spark_df.type=="DEBIT", 2)
                            .when(spark_df.type=="PAYMENT", 3)
                            .when(spark_df.type=="TRANSFER", 4)
                            .otherwise(-1))

spark_df.show()

from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

# Define a function to apply the pipeline to each partition
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def hashingFeatures(pdf):
    # Define stages for the pipeline within the function
    hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="nameOrig", outputCol="nameOrig_hashed", numFeatures=10)
    hashingTF_dest = HashingTF(inputCol="nameDest", outputCol="nameDest_hashed", numFeatures=10)

    # Create the pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[hashingTF, hashingTF_dest])

    # Fit the pipeline to the data
    pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(pdf)

    # Transform the data
    df_hashed = pipeline_model.transform(pdf)

    return df_hashed

# Apply hashing to the DataFrame
df_hashed = spark_df.groupby("nameOrig").apply(hashingFeatures)

df_hashed.show()

Most of the time I am facing this error and buffer overflow!

I have tried different approaches for several days.
